# Laravel redirect with former flashed session

Tags: laravel, session, flash, redirect

how can I redirect within a former flashed session?

For instance, I redirect from the login form with a flashed session (e.g. "Yeah, logged in!") to the dashboard. 
And now I have a second redirect (because of maintenance) in the dashboard controller - but this redirect should also included the former flashed session.

**Step 1**

```
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Yeah, logged in!');
```

**Step 2 in dashboard**

```
return redirect()->route("dashboard_beta");
```

**Step 3 -> view of dashboard_beta**

```
{{ session('status') }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent `HTTP request`, and then will be deleted.

```
 return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Yeah, logged in!');
```

If you need to keep your flash data around for several requests, you may use the `reflash` method, which will keep all of the flash data for an additional request. If you only need to keep specific flash data, you may use the `keep` method:

```
$request->session()->keep('status');
```

[for more laravel sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)